# connect-redis connects to localhost irrespective of provided host

Tags: javascript, redis, node-redis, express-session

I have an `express` server and I am using `connect-redis` with `express-session` to store session to my elasticache instance. But app tries to connect to localhost only.
Here is the error:-

```
config.redisServer.host dev-xxx-site-cache.xxxxx.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com
listening on {"address":"::","family":"IPv6","port":8080}...
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1062:14)
```

while in code I am providing correct host :-

```
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(expressSession);
const redisClient = redis.createClient({ host: config.redisServer.host, port: config.redisServer.port });
redisClient.on('error', err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems to be right, make sure you have not called `createClient()` anywhere else without the hostname and port.

Also, if your `redis` require password, make sure you have provided that also.

Comment: I had used it in one other place. providing credentials there resolved the issue. Thanks anyway.